# Empty XML elements via xsi:nil="true" and nillable="true" in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

Is anyone can help me with xsd.
My XSD looks like:

```
<xs:element name="StringExample" type="xs:string" nillable="true" />
<xs:element name="DateTimeExample" type="xs:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
```

And I want that if `StringExample` is equal to `""` (empty space) or null, the XML should look like :

```
<StringExample />
```

And if DateTimeExample is equal to null then xml should look :

```
<DateTimeExample />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD specifies conditions for the validity of an XML document.  Whether an empty element uses an end tag or an empty tag is not part of those conditions; both forms are equivalent at the XML level and cannot be controlled via XSD.

Any given tool that takes an XSD as input and generates XML as output might be configurable to generate end tags or empty tags; however, no compliant XML processor will care which form is used, so neither should you.

What `nillable="true"` really does is control whether the associated element can have an `xsi:nil` attribute, which is an out-of-band indication that an element's content is nil.  Read more about nil values in the [W3C Schema Part 0: Primer](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/), section [2.9 Nil Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#Nils).